# Extract a zip file denied access

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I'm trying to extract a zip file to another location, and I'm getting denied access error..

CODE:

```
package org.spoutcraft.launcher;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip
{
    List<String> fileList;
    private static final String INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\Level Up! Games" + File.separator + "Perfect World" + File.separator + "Updates" + File.separator + "Launcher.zip";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "C:\\Level Up! Games" + File.separator + "Perfect World";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        UnZip unZip = new UnZip();
        unZip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE,OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    }

    /**
     * Unzip it
     * @param zipFile input zip file
     * @param output zip file output folder
     */
    public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            //create output directory is not exists
            File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
            if(!folder.exists())
            {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            //get the zip file content
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
            //get the zipped file list entry
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

            while(ze!=null)
            {
                String fileName = ze.getName();
                File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

                System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

                //create all non exists folders
                //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                fos.close();   
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }    
}
```

In the main class i've used this code:
After download the zip file:

```
try {
    UnZip.main(null);
```

And im getting this error:

```
file unzip : C:\Level Up! Games\Perfect World\config
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Level Up! Games\Perfect World\config (Acesso negado)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.spoutcraft.launcher.UnZip.unZipIt(UnZip.java:57)
at org.spoutcraft.launcher.UnZip.main(UnZip.java:20)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that in line

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
```

you are creating stream to entry representing ***directory***, where you should only create streams to ***files***.

Try changing your loop to

```
while (ze != null) {

    String fileName = ze.getName();
    File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator
            + fileName);

    System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile);

    // create all non exists folders
    // else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
    if (ze.isDirectory()) {
        newFile.mkdirs();
    } else {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        fos.close();
    }
    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```